# mplayer how do i hide the mplayer window while it is opened?

Tags: mplayer

here is my code , which i currently use and this works fine , i now need to know is it possible i can hide the player window.

```
mplayer -ss 4 -endpos 2 -nosound " & video-link & " -ss 4 -endpos 2 -nosound
```

it closes it after 4 or 2 seconds , it works , how do i hide the player window ?.

i will like the window of mplayer be hidden and of course it will auto close` after xxx seconds.

another question is can mplayer be opened as array to view multipul videos

Comment: Which window do you want to hide? -- The window, where the video is displayed or the terminal window, from where you launch mplayer? -- May I ask why you play with -nosound and want to hide the window. Why play without sound and video? -- And yes, you can start more than one mplayer sessions, for example from different terminal windows, and they can play different video clips or soundtracks. Try and find out how it works :-)

Comment: yes i want to hide the window of the video

Comment: When running in a window, you can click on the minimize control (looks like a minus sign) to hide the window. When running fullscreen, type 'f'  to run in a window, and then  click on the minimize control.

Answer (score 0):

### Using options

Play video but no audio example:

```
mplayer -nosound file.mp4
```

Play audio but no video example:

```
mplayer -vo null file.mp4
```

### Using interactive controls

When running you can type 'm' for 'mute' to toggle between playing the sound and not playing the sound to the speakers or earphones.

When running the video in a window, you can click on the minimize control (looks like a minus sign) to hide the window. When running fullscreen, type 'f' to run in a window, and then click on the minimize control.